# Unknown error when trying to start my react application with Docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, babeljs

I'm relatively new with Docker. When I'm trying to start my react application (which was working perfectly well this morning), I got an error that I can't understand :

```
gui_1     | ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
gui_1     | Error: [BABEL] /appcode/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js: Cannot find module 'gensync'
gui_1     | Require stack:
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/utils.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/package.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/lib/index.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/available-plugins.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/dependencies.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
gui_1     | - /appcode/node_modules/react-app-rewired/scripts/start.js (While processing: "/appcode/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/dependencies.js")
```

Knowing that I'm practicing with docker, I've decided to remove all my images this morning (including the one with the react application on it). So I keep trying to re-build and re-start it again, but I'm always getting this error that I don't understand. I saw that my core-js is deprecated (core-js@2.6.11), which is used with [ant design library](https://ant.design/) (so inside my node_modules/babel-runtime folder).

(error message from docker, when trying to install all the dependencies) :

```
warning antd > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning antd > rc-tree-select > rc-trigger > rc-animate > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

When running my app with CLI (yarn start in the console), everything works fine, that's why I don't understand where the problem come from. Furthermore, I tried to connect to my container and do a `npm i`, and then everything got normal again, but I can't satisfy myself with a bad solution like this.

Thank-you for your answers.

ps : this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
COPY package.json /appcode/
RUN set -x; \
  cd /appcode; \
  yarn install; \
  rm package.json yarn.lock;
```

and my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  server:
    command: sh -c "cd /appcode && ./server.py"
    build:
      context: ./server
      cache_from:
        - ifcopenshell
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - ./server:/appcode

  gui:
    command: sh -c "cd /appcode && yarn && yarn start"
    build: ./gui
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=TRUE
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./gui:/appcode
      - /appcode/node_modules
```

Comment: You Dockerfile is missing the parts that `COPY` in your application code and the default `CMD` to run.  Can you add in the rest of the file?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it, but I have a docker-compose.yml file. I just edited my post to show it.

Comment: Your `volumes:` line tells Docker to always use the version of the `node_modules` tree from the very first time the container ran, and to actively ignore any other updates in the base image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I remedy to this ?

Comment: My recommendation would be to delete all of the `volumes:`, `COPY` your code into your image (and possibly `yarn build` it into static content), and use a local Node for day-to-day development.